# How to implement a semantic search?

Tags: search, 7

How can I add or implement a semantic search functionality in my site?

I have rdfx and schema.org modules in my site to add semantic data to my content so I need a way to add semantic search functionality to my site.

Comment: Can you be more specific in describing what you want your new semantic search to achieve that your current default drupal search does not achieve?  Are you simply interested in achieving more *accurate* results based on semantic metadata or is there something more to what you're hoping to gain?

Comment: I just want an accurate results based on semantic metadata and nothing more for now

Answer (score 1):

The following may or may not meet your needs exactly, but they're ideas.  Since I am now aware of semantic search modules currently available, these would be my workarounds.

The default drupal search does not really provide you with a lot of configuration options to determine which of your nodes' fields/tags can be weighed more heavily when determining search result relevance, I would enable and use the [Apache Solr Search Integration module](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) to get at more accurate search results.

With this module, you can get several benefits:

- It lets you configure different weights, in terms of search result relevance, for the title, body, text in bold, text in comments, as well as terms in all your vocabularies.  This way, you can weigh very heavily the terms from a certain vocabulary, while omitting text from comments and weighing very lightly text that is in terms from another vocabulary (for example) -- adjust weights to your needs.  What I'm suggesting here is that **you can use tagging as a form of search metadata** with this module...  (Author name, etc are also fields that can be weighed with this interface)

[image]

- You can use facets with apachesolr search, which can allow your customers to actually narrow down and interact with search results themselves!  It also provides a 'sort by' block, which users can use to sort results by relevancy (the default), or date, author or type if they prefer.  These aren't exactly what you asked for, but are a way to interactively let users tailor results...  Screenshot below is directly from apachesolr's module [demo site](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_search/).

[image]

To use apachesolr search, however, you have to have to install and configure a solr server for drupal to use: http://drupal.org/node/1053074

Comment: Thank you for your answer but semantic search is a main requirement in my project because it's for a graduation project i'm helping my friend with so i can't use apache solr  is there any other solutions?

Comment: I, myself, can't think of anything else.  Maybe someone else can chime in.  I also prefer to be careful with helping for school-related projects, where work may be expected to be done independently, especially for credit...

Comment: This graduation project require students to do researches and ask about the techniques they are using so it's no problem if i asked about it here and if this question got an answer i'll put it as a reference in the project report so i think there no problem at all

Comment: OK, excellent.  Let's see if someone else can chime in...